# Nikish choosing 5 games question.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Nikish wants to install 5 new games. 2 are word games, 5 quiz and 16 saga. She needs to have at least one of each. How many different selections of games could she choose?

Thanks for any help, the textbook I was using only has the answer at 9080, which I cannot get to.

Comment: See [stars and bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and note the creative ways of altering an equation to convert it into an equation where each variable is non-negative.  Then, if you still can't solve it, please show your work **directly in your query** and ask explicit questions, such as "I've reached such and such a point, what do I do now"?

Comment: More specifically, if you first set up an equation like $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = n$, where $x_1 = $ the  number of word games chosen, your initial constraint on $x_1$ is $1 \leq x_1 \leq 2$.  For an explicit example that handles similar constraints, [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3876263/find-the-number-of-triples-k-1-k-2-k-3-of-integers-such-that/3876421#3876421).

Comment: By the way, I am assuming that the word games are **indistinguishable** from each other, with a similar assumption re the quiz games and the saga games.  If this assumption is **false** then you **can not** use the Stars and Bars methodology.  Instead, you have to manually identify each possible satisfying "solution" to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 5$ and then enumerate how many different ways each specific solution can occur, re the 16 saga games (for example) construed to be distinct from each other.

Comment: Will definitely look into that, it can probably help me answer other related questions. Thanks.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ${2+5+16}\choose{5}$ ways to choose some 5 games.
But we need to exclude ${5+16}\choose{5}$ options when we didn't take any word game, ${2+16}\choose{5}$ options when we didn't take any quiz game and ${2+5}\choose{5}$ options when we didn't take any saga games. But now we excluded twice ${5}\choose{5}$ options, when we took quiz games only and ${16}\choose{5}$ options, when we took saga games only. Let's add them back in, and we get the answer:

$$
{{2+5+16}\choose{5}} - {{5+16}\choose{5}} - {{2+16}\choose{5}} - {{2+5}\choose{5}} + {{5}\choose{5}} + {{16}\choose{5}} \\
= 33649 - 20349 - 8568 - 21 + 1 + 4368 \\
= 9080
$$

Comment: This answer makes complete sense to me, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I still don't understand one thing: if I have to pick one of each game category then nikish has to choose from 2 word games and he has to choose from 5 quiz...etc,  making the conclusion that there are 2 * 5 * 16 possible combinations for his 3 essential game slots.

Comment: Where am I wrong here ^^

Comment: @60q here you are absolutely correct. But after that you probably want to count the number of ways to pick additional two games, and it will be hard not to overcount them. For example, if you pick 1st word game as "essential", and then later choose 2nd word game as "additional", it is the same as choosing 2nd as "essential" and 1st as "additional". Here, look at this question, where this mistake is being made: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956369/whats-wrong-in-my-solution-ways-of-choosing-5-items-from-3-catagory-with-3-6

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. It is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their assessed homework, so giving them the complete answer is a kick in the teeth to the rest of their class.

Comment: @user1729 I partially agree with your comment and partially disagree.  I agree that  it "is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves".  I also think that if their followup question varies significantly from their original question, then they should initiate a new query.  Alternatively, often when an answer is given, the OP will be unclear why a specific step is valid.  When the OP asks such a follow-up question about one of my answers, I will try to make it **crystal clear** why I was allowed to go from *step-a* to *step-b*.

Comment: @user2661923 My comment was referring to the original question, rather than their follow-up comments above. (I agree that clarifying steps in an answer is a good thing.)